# Получить get запрос от post запроса python

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

что делать, если мне нужно получить get запрос от post запроса контента страницы при изменении select тэга , но при этом сам url страницы при изменении select тега не меняется? если пытаться получить контент от post запроса непосредственно, то сам контент также не изменится и при изменение тэга select я буду получать тот же href на одну и ту же картинку на сайте

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://myciclon.com/shop/sergi-ciclon-233601-unique-stock/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
# Находим тег select
select_tag = soup.find('select', {"id": "pa_color"})
if select_tag:
    # Получаем значение из тега select
    options = select_tag.find_all('option')
    print(options)
    for option in options:
        value = option.get('value')
        print(value)
        # Отправляем post запрос с полученным значением
        payload = {'pa_color': value}
        print(payload)
        r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
        # Выполняем get запрос на страницу с обновленными изображениями
        get_response = requests.get(url, r.url)
        get_options_soup = BeautifulSoup(get_response.content, 'html.parser')
        option_id = ''
        value.join(filter(str.isdigit, option_id))

        img_tag = get_options_soup.find('figure', {"class": "woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper"}).find('div').find('a')['href']
        print(img_tag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://myciclon.com/shop/sergi-ciclon-233601-unique-stock/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# 1
select = list(soup.find(id="pa_color").stripped_strings)[1:]
for x in select:
    *_, id_img = x.split()
    print(f'https://myciclon.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/233601-{id_img}.jpg')

# 2
jsn = soup.find(class_="variations_form")['data-product_variations']
for image in json.loads(jsn):
    print(image['image']['url'])
```

Comment: как стать таким же хитрым ?..